# Delphi - How to handle multiple except types

Tags: delphi, exception

I'm willing to handle some errors with a specific function and some other with another function. Is there a way to do that in Delphi without repeating the whole 'on E:X do' block?

For instance, I have the following code:

```
try
  someProcedure()
except
  on E:Error1 do
    thisFunction(E)
  on E:Error2 do
    thisFunction(E)
  on E:Exception do
    thatFunction(E)
end;
```

Could it be written in any way similar to the following, avoinding the repetition of `thisFunction`?

```
try
  someProcedure()
except
  on E:Error1, Error2 do
    thisFunction(E)
  on E:Exception do
    thatFunction(E)
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that syntax is not possible, as you can see in [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)#Try...except_Statements). This restriction is actually reasonable. Indeed, if such syntax were allowed, what type would the `E` variable have?

However, you can use class hierarchies to achieve the same effect. (If you have control over the exception classes, that is. And if it makes sense logically.)

For instance, if

```
type
  EScriptException = class(Exception);
    ESyntaxError = class(EScriptException);
    ERuntimeError = class(EScriptException);
      EDivByZeroError = class(ERuntimeError);
      EAverageOfEmptyList = class(ERuntimeError);
```

then

```
try

except
  on E: ESyntaxError do
    HandleSyntaxError(E);
  on E: EDivByZeroError do
    HandleRuntimeError(E);
  on E: EAverageOfEmptyList do
    HandleRuntimeError(E);
end;
```

can be written

```
try

except
  on E: ESyntaxError do
    HandleSyntaxError(E);
  on E: ERuntimeError do
    HandleRuntimeError(E);
end;
```

If you cannot structure your exception classes like this (or if it doesn't make sense logically), you can of course do something along the lines of

```
try

except
  on E: ESyntaxError do
    HandleSyntaxError(E);
  on E: Exception do
    if (E is EDivByZeroError) or (E is EAverageOfEmptyList) then
      HandleRuntimeError(E);
end;
```

In fact, if you like, you can catch an exception of the `Exception` base class and get full programmatic control over the handling:

```
try

except
  on E: Exception do
    if E is ESyntaxError then
      HandleSyntaxError(E)
    else if (E is EDivByZeroError) or (E is EAverageOfEmptyList) then
      HandleRuntimeError(E)
    else
      raise;
end;
```

(But beware: what happens if you add a trailing semicolon to the line before the last `else`?)

Comment: (I suppose you could let `E` have the type of the closest common ancestor. In many cases, that would be `Exception`.)

Comment: Yes, this is how it works in other languages (e.g. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) or [PHP](https://www.codediesel.com/php/handling-multiple-exceptions-in-php-7-1/)).

Comment: Using separate `is` checks manually is less efficient than using multiple `on` clauses and letting the compiler handle the type checks. For instance, there is slight overhead in re-raising a caught exception vs not catching it in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I agree. But it offers more options, and I want to mention it since the OP seems to request something rather similar.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I couldn't be sure reading the docs that the docs itself was up to date. 
I imagined that could be added after the RTTI was incorporated so  "what type would the E variable have?" would be one of the types I expressed in a specific syntax. But that's ok, I don't have any knowledge about the implementation of the delphi comipler.
Using the hierarchies would generate some unwanted dependencies.

Thanks for the very well explained answer and the provided solution.